# How to create custom diagonal grid lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to do a logarithmic graph with the grid rotated to 45 degrees clockwise, which is kind of complicated. My code is working when the bounds are not too big (here is an example with the following bounds : `xmin = 1`, `xmax = 10`, `ymin = 1`, `ymax = 3`):

[image]

And here is what happens with bigger bounds (`xmin = 1`, `xmax = 100`, `ymin = 1`, `ymax = 30`):

[image]

What can I do in order to have the grid long enough to go through all the plot as expected?

```
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist             import (SubplotHost, GridHelperCurveLinear)
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.grid_finder import (FixedLocator)

fig = plt.figure()

def reciprocity_tr(x, y): return np.log10(x) + np.log10(y), np.log10(y) - np.log10(x)
def reciprocity_inv_tr(x, y): return 10 ** ((x - y) / 2), 10 ** ((x + y) / 2)

xmin = 1
xmax = 100
ymin = 1
ymax = 30

XMIN = np.log10(ymin) + np.log10(xmin)
YMIN = np.log10(ymin) - np.log10(xmin)
XMAX = 2 * np.log10(xmax) + np.log10(ymin) - np.log10(xmin)
YMAX = 2 * np.log10(ymax) - np.log10(ymin) - np.log10(xmin)

grid_locator1 = FixedLocator(np.linspace(10 ** (np.log10(xmin) - np.log10(ymax) + np.log10(xmin)), xmax, num=10))
grid_locator2 = FixedLocator(np.linspace(ymin, 10 ** (np.log10(ymax) + np.log10(xmax) - np.log10(xmin)), num=10))

reciprocity_grid_helper = GridHelperCurveLinear((reciprocity_tr, reciprocity_inv_tr),
                                                grid_locator1=grid_locator1,
                                                grid_locator2=grid_locator2)

reciprocityAxis = SubplotHost(fig, 111, grid_helper=reciprocity_grid_helper)

reciprocityAxis.set_xlim(XMIN, XMAX)
reciprocityAxis.set_ylim(YMIN, YMAX)

fig.add_axes(reciprocityAxis)

reciprocityAxis.grid(True)
reciprocityAxis.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

---

***EDIT :*** There is a good hope using this function:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes import ExtremeFinderFixed

extreme_finder = ExtremeFinderFixed((x1, y1, x2, y2))

reciprocity_grid_helper = GridHelperCurveLinear((reciprocity_tr, reciprocity_inv_tr),extreme_finder=extreme_finder,
                                                grid_locator1=grid_locator1,
                                                grid_locator2=grid_locator2)
```

It appears that this is the way to modify the limit of the grids, the problem is to find the values to put in it... Putting extra large values does not solve the problem. I have nothing more at the moment.